# Powershell New-WebServiceProxy Async methods

Tags: c#, wcf, powershell, asynchronous

I have a WCF library exposing some useful information and I query them from powershell with `New-WebServiceProxy` cmdlet

```
$link = "http://localhost/Rlib/Rlib.Info.svc";
$service = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $link;
```

Assume I have a function like `GetLastData()`, I usually invoke it this way

```
$service.GetLastData()
```

Now I've a very slow function that requires lot of time to complete (complex DB query that return a date), I see that an Async function is automatically generated and I can Invoke it using `$service.GetLastDataAsync()`. How does it work? Once I call the async method how can I check if data are available and recover them?

Comment: Does the `$service` object have a `GetLastDataCompleted` event as well?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't return any value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does it work?

`GetLastDataAsync` returns `Task<something>`, which can be used to track the process of an out-going operation. It can get quite complicated. You probably don't need to use async version, unless you have good reason to? You can use powershell jobs for synchronous version, and just poll how the job is doing.

> Once I call the async method how can I check if data are available and
>   recover them?

If you would like to wait for result, you could do `GetLastDataAsync(..).Result`, but this would be useless, as you can already use the *synchronous* one.

There is no easy way in my opinion to consume Task correctly. The closest I found was to use some kind of custom DLL, in this manner:

```
    C:\PS> $path = "$home\Pictures\foo.png"
    C:\PS> $asyncOp = [Windows.Storage.StorageFile]::GetFileFromPathAsync($path)
    C:\PS> Add-Type -Path ~\PoshWinRT.dll
    C:\PS> $typeName = 'PoshWinRT.AsyncOperationWrapper[Windows.Storage.StorageFile]'
    C:\PS> $wrapper = new-object $typeName -Arg $asyncOp
    C:\PS> $file = $wrapper.AwaitResult()
    C:\PS> $file
```

The theory behind wrapper is that it's using `Task.Wait` behind the scenes, which kind of beats the whole purpose of `async`. As it's still blocking the main thread.

**TLDR; stick with synchronized version & scheduled jobs if you need.**

https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2013/09/30/calling-winrt-async-methods-from-windows-powershell/

Comment: Thank you for the complete explanation. I think using `New-Job` on the synchronous method is a much more viable solution for my situation

Answer (score 3):

After you call the `Async` method, a corresponding event will be raised when the operation is finished (in your case `GetLastDataCompleted`).

You can use [`Register-ObjectEvent`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849929.aspx) to "listen" for when this event is raised!

I used [CDYNE's IP2Geo service](http://wiki.cdyne.com/index.php/IP2Geo) for a quick test, but the idea is exactly the same with any other SOAP service:

```
$ServiceUri = 'http://ws.cdyne.com/ip2geo/ip2geo.asmx?wsdl'
$Service = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $ServiceUri

# Make sure the environment is clean
Remove-Variable -Scope Global -Name IPResult -Force | Out-Null
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier "IPResolved"

# Register an event subscription
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $Service -EventName ResolveIPCompleted -SourceIdentifier "IPResolved" -Action { $Global:IPResult = $args[1] } | Out-Null

# Initialize the operation with Async
$Service.ResolveIPAsync('8.8.8.8','')

# Do other stuff in the background here

# Wait for the variable to get populated
while(-not(Get-Variable -Scope Global -Name IPResult -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)){
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}

# Let's see what we got!
if($Global:IPResult.Error -eq $null){
    Write-Host "Success!"

    # The Result property holds the result from the operation
    $Global:IPResult.Result

} else {
    Write-Host "Failed!"
}
```

Comment: It would be far easier just to poll the Task.IsCompleted property (from ResolveIPAsync)